# Error during template rendering (NoReverseMatch) in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to submit the form to my view:

**in trending.html:**

```
{% extends 'djangobin/base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% load humanize %}

{% block title %}
    Trending {{ lang.name }} Snippets - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

    <h5><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Trending {{ lang.name }} Snippets</h5>
    <hr>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Hits</th>
            <th>Language</th>
            <th>User</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        {% for snippet in snippets %}
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fas fa-globe"></i>
                    <a href="{{ snippet.get_absolute_url }}">{{ snippet.title }}</a>
                </td>
                <td title="{{ snippet.created_on }}">{{ snippet.created_on|naturaltime }}</td>
                <td>{{ snippet.hits }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'trending_snippets' snippet.language.slug  %}">{{ snippet.language }}</a></td>
                {% if not snippet.user.profile.private %}
                    <td><a href="{{ snippet.user.profile.get_absolute_url }}">{{ snippet.user.username|title }}</a></td>
                {% else %}
                    <td>-</td>
                {% endif %}

            </tr>
        {% empty %}
            <tr class="text-center">
                <td colspan="4">There are no snippets.</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

**in views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, render, redirect, get_object_or_404, reverse
from .forms import SnippetForm
from .models import Language, Snippet

def trending_snippets(request, language_slug=''):
    lang = None
    snippets = Snippet.objects
    if language_slug:
        snippets = snippets.filter(language__slug=language_slug)
        lang = get_object_or_404(Language, slug=language_slug)
    snippets = snippets.all()
    return render(request, 'djangobin/trending.html', {'snippets': snippets, 'lang': lang})
```

**in urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views as views
urlpatterns = [
    url('^trending/$', views.trending_snippets, name='trending_snippets'),
    url('^trending/(?P<language_slug>[\w]+)/$', views.trending_snippets, name='trending_snippets'),
]
```

**I got the following error:**

NoReverseMatch at /trending/
Reverse for 'trending_snippets' with arguments '('c-sharp',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['trending/(?P[\w]+)/$', 'trending/$']

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

Error during template rendering

**Reference website:** overiq.com

**Reference website Link:** https://overiq.com/django-1-11/creating-trending-snippet-page/

**Python version:** 3.8.2

**Django version:** 3.0.5

**OS:** Windows 8.1(32 bit)

Comment: Which version of Django are you running?

Comment: version of Django - 3.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `c-sharp`, which contains a hyphen, you need to change `[\w]` to `[-\w]`.

```
url('^trending/(?P<language_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.trending_snippets, name='trending_snippets'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a slug field you're matching, you can use the [built-in slug path converter Django provides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) to match it by using `path` instead of `url`.

Change:

```py
url('^trending/(?P<language_slug>[\w]+)/$', views.trending_snippets, name='trending_snippets'),
```

to:

```py
path('trending/<slug:language_slug>)/', views.trending_snippets, name='trending_snippets'),
```

Note that `slug:`matches hyphens, underscores, and also ASCII letters and numbers.

`url()` is just an alias to `re_path()` and [may be deprecated in the future](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#url), so you should change your code accordingly.